# play application startup isses with VM variable -Dprecopiled=true?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I'm using play1-1.3.0. In production mode, I'm starting up my application, by using this command `play start MyApp -Dprecompiled=true` i got this error message in logs.

```
play:424 - Precompiled classes are missing!!
```

I exactly don't know why I'm getting this error message.

Comment: Have you tried running a play clean MyApp first?

Answer (score 0):

You need to of ran play precompile first this will compile classes ready to use